# Make Discord Bot post image from the link from the message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make discord bot post image from the text.

For example - 
If someone types
!image [http://imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg](https://imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg)

then the bot should reply back with the image without link.
Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: How are you handling arguments & commands? Please post the code of what you have tried

Comment: Use regex to find the link

Comment: I managed it to get it working, But what is Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a example how you could do it:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const imageUrl = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1);

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setImage(imageUrl)
msg.channel.send{ embed }
```